# Using Django-Wiki with Angular

Tags: python, django, angularjs, wiki

I'm building a large application with Django and Angular. One portion of the app should be a fully-fledged wiki. Rather than reinvent the wheel, I looked at [Django-Wiki](https://github.com/django-wiki/django-wiki) as a good wiki implementation.

The problem is I need to incorporate it into my single-page Angular app, which makes data requests to Django's [REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). How can I make Django avoid connecting to the Angular single page app for requests to certain URLs, say "/wiki"?

If there is an Angular plugin that creates a wiki interface, that would also be really helpful.